# How to call function bundled by Webpack in Electron main js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, commonjs

I'm trying to access a function from my (webpack'ed) bundle, but the function is undefined. (The entire object in empty) (In electron-main.js see `appBundle.test()`)

I've been searching all over the web, but can't find the answer I'm looking for.
Tried all the different libraryTarget options, but none of them worked the way I expected.

Here is the source code:

webpack.dev.js:

```html
...

module.exports = Merge(CommonConfig, {
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    watch: true,

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/wwwroot/resources/js/components",
        publicPath: "/resources/js/components/",
        library: "appBundle",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },

    plugins: ([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development")
            }
        }),

        // Etract CSS
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        }),
    ]),
})
```

index.ts:

```html
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

// Styling
import './application-styling.scss';

// Application
import "./application/index.tsx";

export default function test() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

electron-main.js:

```html
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const createAppWindow = require('../main/app-process');
const authService = require('../services/auth-service');

global.window = {}; // <- Need to define this manually, else the require call throws errors

const appBundle = require('app-bundle'); // Trying to import the bundle.js here

let win = null;

function createAuthWindow() {
    destroyAuthWin();

    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            enableRemoteModule: false
        }
    });

    win.loadURL(authService.getAuthenticationURL());

    const { session: { webRequest } } = win.webContents;

    const filter = {
        urls: [
            'http://localhost/callback*'
        ]
    };

    webRequest.onBeforeRequest(filter, async ({ url }) => {

        console.log(appBundle); // <- undefined or empty object, depending on libraryTarget
        console.log(appBundle.test()); // <- error, test is undefined

        await authService.loadTokens(url);
        createAppWindow();
        return destroyAuthWin();
    });
    ...
}


...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `import "./application/index.tsx";` call somehow messed up the exports. When I just used a clean file as the entry point it worked fine.

Anyway I ended up just building the electron project together with the app bundle into one package.